# Create identity matrix with Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, identity, shapes

I want to create an identity matrix with this shape: (1601, 2, 2) but I don't know how to do it. I tried with np.eye without succes
May someone could help me please?

Answer (score 0):

use [`numpy.identity`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.identity.html), pass 2 to create 2x2 identity matrix, create numpy array of 1601 such matrices.

```py
np.array([np.identity(2)]*1601)

array([[[1., 0.],
        [0., 1.]],
       [[1., 0.],
        [0., 1.]],
       [[1., 0.],
        [0., 1.]],
       ...,
       [[1., 0.],
        [0., 1.]],
       [[1., 0.],
        [0., 1.]],
       [[1., 0.],
        [0., 1.]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `numpy.broadcast_to` ([see docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html)) to expand your 2-dim array through a third dimension.

```
import numpy as np

np.broadcast_to(np.eye(2, 2), (1601, 2, 2))
```